# Incentivizing facebook likes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I submitted the review for the getting the permission publish_actions for my app on website. I need to track which user like which of my pages locally. I was thinking of Graph Api
I was planning CURL POST for the following [URL](https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILEID/og.likes?object=mypage.com&access_token=MYTOKEN)

Which require 'publish_actions' permission.

But review team says

**Your app experience does not need the requested permission. Please see information that is already available through the public_profile field.**

I actually need to do the following

1. User will visit the page
2. User will like the page

3  User will be awarded bonus for likes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IN short "dont do that"**

Incentivizing likes are against Facebook Platform Policy

Facebook platform policy  clearly says

**Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.**

Check section 4.5 on https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

also check https://www.facebook.com/help/354719754598906